# How to send mail via smtp using ssl in php

Tags: ssl, smtp, pear, php

How can I send mail via smtp using ssl? We are able to send the simple text mail, but it's not allowing the links or certain tags in the mail to pass, we tried using pear-mail.

Please suggest any options.

We are using third party GMAIL and hosting is in Godaddy. All mx record are fine and earlier we were able to deviver mails when we have not used ssl, also as i mentioned we are able to send the simple text mails with ssl, so please no answers regarding hostings, just any options how to use it with ssl.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at phpmailer.  You can use phpmailer to send outgoing messages through gmail's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com), and it has options to connect to the SMTP server by SSL.  phpmailer is very simple to setup - just a few PHP files to copy to your server. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. You can start sending mail using the simple example at the github page above as a boilerplate.