# PHP email encryption

Tags: php, encryption

I have a website with an SSL.

I would like to encrypt outgoing emails from my server. I've been digging around at this and I really don't know where to begin.

Here is my PHP email script so you have an idea of what I'm using:

```
public function email($to, $title, $message){
    $from = "angela@mysite.com";
    $headers = "From: {$from}\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: {$from}\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: {$from}\r\n";
    $headers .= "Organization: InfiniSys, inc.\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

    $subject = $title;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Ubuntu 14.04

I'm not sure if this is a server setting or programming config.

Very interesting post: (can't remember where I got it)

```
<?php
// Setup mail headers.
$headers = array("From" => "someone@example.com",
    "To" => "someone-else@example.com",
    "Cc" => "spam@somewhere.org",
    "Subject" => "Encrypted mail readable with most clients",
    "X-Mailer" => "PHP/".phpversion()
);

// Get the public key certificate.
$pubkey = file_get_contents("C:\test.cer");

// Remove some double headers for mail()
$headers_msg = $headers;
unset($headers_msg['To'], $headers_msg['Subject']);
$data = <<

This email is Encrypted!

You must have my certificate to view this email!

Me

EOD;

//write msg to disk
$fp = fopen("C:\msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

// Encrypt message
openssl_pkcs7_encrypt("C:\msg.txt","C:\enc.txt",$pubkey,$headers_msg,PKCS7_TEXT,1);

// Seperate headers and body for mail()
$data = file_get_contents("C:\enc.txt");
$parts = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);

// Send mail
mail($headers['To'], $headers['Subject'], $parts[1], $parts[0]);

// Remove encrypted message (not fot debugging)
//unlink("C:\msg.txt");
//unlink("C:\enc.txt");
?>
```

Comment: if you want advanced control over the outgoing emails, you should use an SMTP library for PHP (a simple google search will suffice) instead of PHP's built in mail() function.

Comment: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) comes highly recommended as does [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) but for my own encrypted emails I have not found anything beats [GnuPG](https://www.gpg4win.org/)

Comment: Its worth noting that emails in general are ***not at all secured***, you can try to obscure and encrypt emails as you send them but without end-to-end encryption as with a third party public/private key system such as GnuPG it's somewhat like trying to write a postcard in code, it's still a postcard the mailman is reading and looking at the picture and recording the destination from/to the stamp....

Answer (score 6):

Try Using PHPMAILER It's really Easy
You can find all Username and password from your Cpanel Email Account option

```
$to= "example@gmail.com";
require 'phpmailerlibrary/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'support@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('support@twekr.com', 'example Inc.');
$mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('support@example.com', 'Support');
$mail->addCC($to);
$mail->addBCC($to);


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Subject of Email';
$mail->Body    = 'Content of your html email';
$mail->AltBody = 'Please Upgrade Your Browser to view this email';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo "Unable to send email"; exit;
}
```

You should Use TLS as it is also encryption method 90% website uses including google too.

Comment: Please keep this answer up, as it is a very good answer and i might look back at this; However, i would like to stay away from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Sagar you may be interested to know that no one actually uses SSL technology it's defunct and broken, everyone uses TLS but the *name* SSL remains.

Comment: @Martin but web hosting provider gives us an option to send email via ssl

Comment: @SagarSingh read this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/whats-the-difference-between-ssl-tls-and-https

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748122/how-to-send-mail-via-smtp-using-ssl-in-php) where a user suggests to use PHP Mailer.

> You can use phpmailer to send outgoing messages through gmail's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com), and it has options to connect to the SMTP server by SSL. phpmailer is very simple to setup - just a few PHP files to copy to your server.

Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/php/send-plain-text-e-mail-from-php-using-gmail-secure-smtp-server)

If you don't want to use a third library, you'll need to communicate with a SMTP server using `socket` and send all the commands manually.

Check out this [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt) to know how the protocol works

Comment: unfortunately, i have already ran into that suggestion; I would rather do this using the native php mail function for my purposes.

Comment: That will be complicated, according to PHP Mailer sources, you need to use `socket` to communicate with the `SMTP` server manually.

Comment: I am using my own email server.

Comment: @ASDKFHASKDFJAS Is he using the SMTP protocol?

Comment: link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @ASDKFHASKDFJAS I think if you're denying youself 3rd party mailers due to having your own private mail server you really are not understanding what the mailer class is actually doing.